# Backend choice for android app

Tags: android, python, django, google-app-engine, backend

I'm new to android ,the app i'm building  will do some computation on some lat,long values retrieved from a database and plot it on a map and also make some API calls.It will also store the user profiles .I am familiar with python so I'm planning to Build the back-end using Google App Engine.I was wondering if that is the right choice or are there any better choices available

Comment: backend as in database like mysql or something?

Comment: no API , as i found out we should not connect the database directly to the APP,we should use a RESTful API /Web Services Instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any back-end, in which you feel comfortable, your just have to provide web services for Android. Google App Engine & python is as good as any other. Only thing which matter is your comfort or experience (in a particular platform).

Some other options are:

- PHP, MySql
- Java (see [Spark Framework](http://sparkjava.com/))
- Scala/Java [Playframework](https://www.playframework.com/)
- & Many other